# Read/Write permission of 2nd hard drive

Tags: partitioning, permissions, mount, hard-drive, fstab

I know that this question is asked before, but nothing seems to work. I have a double boot windows 10 - ubuntu 18.10 on the NVME and a 2nd 1 TB HDD drive (ntfs). Windows of course have permission on the HDD, but ubuntu doesn't (read-only).

I want to have read-write-execute permission as user (id=1000) on the HDD!

tried:

1. remount

   sudo mount -o remount,rw  
   Sometimes works after 1st reboot, but after 2nd reboot, I had read-only permissions again
2. edit fstab

default entry:

> /dev/disk/by-uuid/[disk-id] /path/to/mount auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

changed to:

> /dev/disk/by-uuid/[disk-id] /path/to/mount auto nosuid,rw,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

,

> /dev/disk/by-uuid/[disk-id] /path/to/mount auto nosuid,uid=1000,nodev,rw,nofail,x-gvfs-show

,

> /dev/disk/by-uuid/[disk-id] /path/to/mount ntfs defaults

,

> /dev/disk/by-uuid/[disk-id] /path/to/mount ntfs-3g defaults

,

> dev/disk/by-uuid/[disk-id] /path/to/mount ntfs nosuid,uid=1000,nodev,rw,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

3. chown

   sudo chown -R -v user:user /path/to/mount

error: failed to change ownership of '/path/to/mount' from user:root to user:user
,

```
chown -R user /path/to/mount
```

didn't work

As far as I understand, permissions are granted upon mount on boot time. So, the solution has to lie at fstab. But, the mount point is at /media/ (or by default at /mnt/) which are directories with only-root permissions, thus I tried to mount under /home/user/testDir, but got the error:

> mount: /home/user/testDir: mount point not mounted or bad option

Any suggestions? Maybe, in how to properly edit fstab?
Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Have you disabled fast boot in Windows?

Comment: If it's NTFS then you probably need to manage permissions on the Windows side. Have you tried creating an EXT4 partition to manage with Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, disabling fast boot in Windows did work!

Thank you both a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most common cause is Fast Boot in Windows.
For that (in Windows):

- Go to 'Control Panel':
- Select 'Power Options'
- Select 'Choose what the power buttons do'
- Select 'Change settings that are currently unavailable'
- Unselect 'Turn on fast startup (recommended)' so that the check-mark disappears.
- Click Save changes.
  Done.

Comment: As you may notice, I am a new contributor and I need 15+ reputation to upvote.