# How to make new folder on HDD

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, directory

I am new to this (first day starting) and want to figure out how to make and delete files on my HDD. When i right click the "new folder" option is greyed out and if i delete anything this error comes up: You do not have sufficient permissions to delete file x.. Error removing file: Read-only file system.

Thanks

Comment: If you are on Ubuntu dual boot with Windows. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130896/read-write-permission-of-2nd-hard-drive/1130909#1130909)

Comment: Where are are you trying to make a new folder? New system folders  require root permission. If you are making a new folder in your home folder then that option should not be greyed out.

Comment: Only using ubuntu as my OS on my SSD. I am trying to make a folder so I can put the steam games and pics/videos on my HDD.

Comment: It's best to make a new partition, label it 'Data', then  move all your data folders/files to this partition. That way, it's easier to back up your data and keeps it separate from Linux system files and user partition configuration files.